# get iframe onload element

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube

I have `<iframe src="myYouTubeLink" onload="test">`

how can I get to the iFrame **src** into the "test" function?

```js
function test() {
  // obtain the iframe src 
  var code = false;
  if (code)
    alert('code: ' + code);
}
```

```html
<h2>this is the video</h2>
<div style="width:150px">
  <div class="video-container">
    <iframe id="test456" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/amDMGIyyrlw" onload="test()">
    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the **[codepen](http://codepen.io/serhio/pen/XdpGGy?editors=1010)**...

**PS.**

I need to obtain from the test the caller, then the caller.src... cause I will use same function for multiple elements.

Answer (score 2):

Since there was a jQuery tag in the question, here's a jQuery answer. Of course, you will need a reference to the jQuery library in your page for this to work.

HTML:

```
<h2>this is the video</h2>
<div style="width:150px">
    <div class="video-container">
        <!-- note: removed the onload definition from the iframe element -->
        <iframe id="test456" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/amDMGIyyrlw"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
//jquery document ready event -- fires when document is first loaded
$('document').ready(function(){

    //attach an onload event handler to each iframe     
    //(can change the selector to select specific iframes)
    $('iframe').load(function(e){

        //the jquery event will automatically have a target 
        //property that is set to the element that fired the event
        //you can pull the src property from that
        alert(e.target.src);

        //pass the target element to a test function
        test(e.target);
    });
});

function test(iframe){
    //check src or other properties to see if the element passes or fails the test
    //example: testing that the value is not the empty string
    //but any check can be done here depending on requirements
    if(iframe.src != ""){

        //check any properties of the iframe

        //pass or fail

        //perform other actions as needed
    }
}
```

Comment: plus +1 for removing js function calls from the DOM markup. That's more better.

Comment: Imagine I have dynamic load of 100 videos. 50 of them should pass the test other 50 shouldn't... So I need to say individually to each video if it `test()` or not...

Comment: Updated code sample to show how you could pass the target object (which represents the iframe) to any function you'd like to perform other logic.

Answer (score 1):

Is a reference an option for you?

```
<h2>this is the video</h2>
<div style="width:150px">
  <div class="video-container">
    <iframe id="test456" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/amDMGIyyrlw" onload="test(this)"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function test(caller){
  // obtain the iframe src 
  // then youtube embed code
    alert(caller.id);
  var code = false;
  if (code)
    alert('code: ' + code);
}
```